# Create a nested view template

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs, and I'm creating the nested view template like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview

But the code I have is of different type. For routing, it uses this:

```
awfApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    var states = [
        { name: 'home', isDefault: true }, //TODO: Moure a awf 
        { name: 'module1', module: { title: "Module 01", img: "modul1.png" } },
        { name: 'module2', module: { title: "Module 02", img: "modul2.png" } },
        { name: 'mainlist4', module: { title: "Main List4", img: "modul2.png" } },
        { name: 'mainlist2', module: { title: "Main List2", img: "modul2.png" } },
        { name: 'mainlist', module: { title: "Main List", img: "modul2.png" } }
    ];
    if (appConfig.doLogin)
        states.push({ name: 'articles', module: { title: "Articles", img: "articles.png" } });

});
```

Please tell me, how can create nested views in AngularJs using the code above.
Thanks

Comment: You are using a module called angular-ui-router. Read more [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Comment: this is diffrent from the code i used.

Comment: this is diffrent from the code i used. Code used in gievn link for rounting is :
`$stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
    })
    .state('state1.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.list.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
      }
    })
});`

Comment: Is that really the whole code? It is creating an array of objects, and that's it. Is not calling method `.state` of `$stateProvider`, so it seems to me that something is missing.